# How do I implement touch listener on PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Spent so much time reading the answers and now it's time to ask my first question here.

I am trying to implement some kind of **touch listener** so user could swipe back to the main screen from **PreferenceActivity**.

But it looks like it can't be implemented in common way. **OnTouchEvent** of activity and **getListView().setOnTouchListener** don't fire when I'm swiping. Any ideas how to fix it?

I am using a **public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment** to display settings btw.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found solution. Use **dispatchTouchEvent** callback method to listen touch events from whole activity surface